# Better solution for HTML element slide from right with CSS transform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have a side bar with fixed width that slides in from the right, and then slides back out when dismissed.

What I'm doing is is changing the side bar's display to block, and adding an animate class on a user click.

I've created a keyframe to move it to the right in .3s, but unless I use a javascript function to set the display back to none (after 300 milliseconds) it'll just be hanging out on the right edge of the screen. This works but seems hacky, is there a nicer way to do this?

Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wLL468jj/1/

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

Here's the JS that adds a class to animate to the right then set display to none.

```
$("#popup").addClass('animate-right');
setTimeout(function(){ popup.style.display = "none" }, 300);
```

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: Sorry, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/wLL468jj/1/

Comment: Not certain what issue is? If comment `setTimeout` same effect appears to be rendered?

Comment: Yeah it works, but I felt like there's a better way to do something like this, but maybe I'm being too hard on myself.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to hook into the `animationend` event that fires when a css animation has completed ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend)).

This event isn't standard in all browsers so you can use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to get the correct event name depending on the browser. Something like this:

```
var animEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd',
        'OAnimation': 'oAnimationEnd',
        'msAnimation': 'MSAnimationEnd',
        'animation': 'animationend'
    },
    // animation end event name
    animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('animation')];
```

Now you can use the variable `animEndEventName` and add a listener for that event. Something like this maybe:

```
   $("#popup").on(animEndEventName, function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('animate-right'))
            $(this).hide();
    });
```

This should give you a rough idea, you obviously may need to tweak somethings for your setup.